# need to use coustum domain for azure rather than the default one https://XXXXXX.82b7a2cbfe014dfc8f63.westeurope.aksapp.io/

Tags: azure-aks

HI i have a application in azure aks i dont want to use the https://XXXXX.82b7a2cbfe014dfc8f63.westeurope.aksapp.io/ default on i need to open this app as example.com i created redirect policy and try to create cname also but didn't work

Configure DNS: Update the DNS settings for your domain to point to your AKS cluster. There are two approaches you can take:

```
CNAME Record: Create a CNAME record that points your domain (e.g., example.com) to the default AKS app domain (e.g., XXXXX.82b7a2cbfe014dfc8f63.westeurope.aksapp.io). This can be done through your domain registrar or DNS provider's configuration interface.

A Record: Create an A record that maps your domain (e.g., example.com) to the IP address of your AKS cluster's ingress/load balancer. Note that this IP address may change if your cluster scales or undergoes maintenance. Ensure you have a static IP or update the A record accordingly.l
```

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
name: my-ingress
spec:
rules:
- host: example.com
http:
paths:
- path: /
pathType: Prefix
backend:
service:
name: your-service-name
port:
number: 80
TLS Termination (optional): If you want to enable HTTPS for your custom domain, you can configure TLS termination by adding TLS-related annotations and providing SSL certificates.

Apply Changes: Apply the Ingress resource configuration to your AKS cluster using kubectl apply -f <filename.yaml>.

Ingress Controller: Set up an Ingress Controller in your AKS cluster to handle incoming traffic. This allows you to define rules for routing requests to different services based on the incoming domain.

Ingress Resource: Create an Ingress resource in your AKS cluster to define the routing rules for your application. Specify the custom domain (e.g., example.com) as the host in the Ingress resource.